# Help with a simple email script for OSX

Tags: email, applescript

I would be so happy if someone could assist me in creating an Applescript to send some emails. I have seen a few examples but I am not confident that I can adapt them to my own needs.

I need to send the same email (subject & body), one at a time, to a list of addresses on a .csv file. I am using Apple Mail 5.3 and OSX 10.7.5

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help out.

Here's what I have so far.

```
    tell application "Mail"

    tell (make new outgoing message)
        set theAddress to "xxxx"
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
        set subject to "xxxx"
        set content to "xxxx"
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

I need to set theAddress to cell A1 on my excel sheet. How do I point it there? Once the email has sent I need to point it to cell A2... and so on.

Comment: Requests for scripts are best received when the person asking the question provides some sample code of what they've tried to date that hasn't worked.

Comment: Can you also give us some sample data from your CSV? Different CSVs often have different escaping rules and it can be hard to work with.

Comment: Actually is doesn't have to be a csv. I just thought they were the easiest to work with. The list is currently an XLS file with 1 column containing many rows of email addresses.

Comment: Are you trying to learn applescript or just get the job done? If you just want to get the job done automator can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and quickest way to do this in other languages would just be to drop each of your columns from excel into a list (array) and then have the whole thing in a loop and it will create the email fill the information and then send the email then loop back to the beginning and start again with values from each of the arrays at [1] and so on from there through your list. Not the most professional or efficient way but for your purposes that would work. If you can implement that then go ahead. If not I'll script it when I get back to my desktop.

----edit----

I edited script first written on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386794/applescript-for-sending-emails-from-a-list-in-excel

to achieve this script. I code in java mostly so this might not be perfect so maybe somebody can come along and tweak it.
OP should go through and enter his own values for the things written in all caps. Also the excel sheet needs to be in the form that the OP from the links excel sheet is in

```
set {firstName, eAddress} to getData()

repeat with i from 1 to count firstName
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"INSERT SUBJECT HERE"}
    tell mymail
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:item i of eAddress}
--The next line will start each email with Hi firstName and then carriage return to the text you fill in below

        set content to "Hi " & item i of firstName & "

INSERT BODY OF EMAIL HERE"
    end tell
    --show message window (otherwise it's hidden)
    set visible of mymail to true
    --bring Mail to front
    activate
    send mymail
end tell
end repeat


on getData()
set colA to {}
set colB to {}
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    activate
    tell active sheet
        set lastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 1) direction toward the top)

        repeat with i from 3 to lastRow
            set end of colA to (value of range ("A" & i))
            set end of colB to (value of range ("B" & i))
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

return {colA, colB}
end getData
```

Comment: Like I said when I get back to my desktop I'll script it for you

Comment: You could go through all the work of making excel play nice with mail but since you're just using excel to kept your lists and not anything more extravagant Id say just to read the AppleScript doc from apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html . Just look into how to build lists and loops and it should be easy enough

Comment: I will look it over and edit it to work do you shortly. But I just realized a much easier way to do this is to create a group in your contacts. Mail has a utility built in to it for exactly this purpose using groups in contacts

Comment: Works like a charm. I just needed to add 2 blank rows to the top of the excel sheet. Thank you so much for your help Jake, you really saved my bacon!

Comment: Do you want me to take the two blank spaces away?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to start off with reading the XLS file with AppleScript (and then `tell "Mail"` for each address you find). As a starter you can consult

- [How to read excel data in background using applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217362/how-to-read-excel-data-in-background-using-applescript)
- [Introduction to Scripting Microsoft Excel](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.02/2302AppleScript/index.html)
- [Using AppleScript with Excel for Mac](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113891/en-us)

and work your way up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to send call for papers. It sends batches of 90 emails in BCC from a list of 1000 emails. It is an AppleScript.

```
set title to "Call for papers conference XXX"
set body to read "/Users/ber/Desktop/bod_of_email.txt" as «class utf8»
set addresses to read "/Users/ber/Desktop/mail/email_list_one_email_per_row.txt" as «class utf8»
set bccRecipients to {}
set c to 0

repeat with e in paragraphs of addresses
    if length of e is greater than 10 then
            copy e to the end of the bccRecipients
        set c to c + 1
        if c = 90 then
            tell application "Mail"
                activate
                tell (make new outgoing message)
                    set visible to true
                    make new recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"conference@chair.com"}
                    repeat with thisRecipient in bccRecipients as list
                        make new bcc recipient at end of bcc recipients with properties {address:thisRecipient}
                    end repeat
                    set subject to title
                    set content to body
                    send
                    delay 3
                end tell
            end tell
            set bccRecipients to {}
            set c to 0
        end if
    end if
end repeat
```